# Scikit-learn Minibatch KMeans: sparse vs dense matrix clustering

Tags: optimization, scipy, scikit-learn

I just wrote a piece of code that I'm having trouble to understand, any help would be really appreciated. The question is: why does clustering over a sparse matrix take so much more time, more memory, and behave differently than clustering over the same matrix in dense format?

Here is the code. It's simply doing the following, for a dense and a sparse matrix:

1. Create a 100K x 500 matrix
2. Fit a MinibatchKMeans estimator over the matrix (we don't care about the result)
3. Display the time it took to fit the estimator

Between the two benchmarks, memory is manually garbage collected (to make sure we're on a fresh start).

```
#!.env/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import time
import gc
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from memory_profiler import profile


@profile
def bench_dense():
    print ">>>>> Dense Matrix Clustering"
    # create a random dense matrix
    dense_matrix = np.random.random((
        100000,  # 100K 'fake' documents
        500  # 500 dimensions
    ))
    s = time.time()
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(
        n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', batch_size=100, n_init=10, verbose=1)
    km.fit_predict(dense_matrix)  # cluster the points
    print "Clustered dense matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)


@profile
def bench_sparse():
    print ">>>>>> Sparse Matrix Clustering"
    # convert the dense matrix in sparse format
    sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(np.random.random((
        100000,  # 100K 'fake' documents
        500  # 500 dimensions
    )))
    s = time.time()
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(
        n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', batch_size=100, n_init=10, verbose=1)
    km.fit_predict(sparse_matrix)
    print "Clustered sparse matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(42)
    bench_dense()
    gc.collect()
    np.random.seed(42)
    bench_sparse()
```

When running this code a few times (to make sure stochastic nature of the KMeans algorithm is not the reason of my findings), I had a few surprises:

- Why does it take ~40 times more iterations for the clustering algorithm to converge when using the dense representation of the matrix?
- Why does it take twice as much time to converge using the sparse representation compared to the dense one, although there is much less iterations performed?
- Finally, I guess the reason why more memory is allocated during the sparse version of the benchmark is because the matrix (being randomly created) doesn't contain any 0, which makes the sparse format less memory-efficient. Am I right?

Here is the output of the benchmark:

```
>>>>> Dense Matrix Clustering
Init 1/10 with method: k-means++
Inertia for init 1/10: 11546.570096
[...]
Init 10/10 with method: k-means++
Inertia for init 10/10: 11554.093346
Minibatch iteration 1/100000: mean batch inertia: 42.160602, ewa inertia: 42.160602 
Minibatch iteration 2/100000: mean batch inertia: 41.914472, ewa inertia: 42.160110 
[...]
Minibatch iteration 977/100000: mean batch inertia: 41.750966, ewa inertia: 41.581670 
Minibatch iteration 978/100000: mean batch inertia: 41.719181, ewa inertia: 41.581945 
Converged (lack of improvement in inertia) at iteration 978/100000
Computing label assignment and total inertia
Clustered dense matrix in: 7.363s
Filename: experiments/dense_sparse_bench.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13     33.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    14                             def bench_dense():
    15                                 # create a random dense matrix
    16     33.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       dense_matrix = np.random.random((
    17                                     100000,  # 100K 'fake' documents
    18    241.2 MiB    208.0 MiB           500  # 500 dimensions
    19                                 ))
    20    241.3 MiB      0.1 MiB       s = time.time()
    21    241.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       km = MiniBatchKMeans(
    22    241.4 MiB      0.2 MiB           n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', batch_size=100, n_init=10, verbose=1)
    23    405.0 MiB    163.6 MiB       km.fit_predict(dense_matrix)  # cluster the points
    24    405.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       print "Clustered dense matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)

>>>>> Sparse Matrix Clustering
Init 1/10 with method: k-means++
Inertia for init 1/10: 11618.817774
[...]
Init 10/10 with method: k-means++
Inertia for init 10/10: 11609.579624
Minibatch iteration 1/100000: mean batch inertia: 42.105951, ewa inertia: 42.105951 
Minibatch iteration 2/100000: mean batch inertia: 42.375899, ewa inertia: 42.106491 
[...]
Minibatch iteration 21/100000: mean batch inertia: 41.912611, ewa inertia: 42.258551 
Minibatch iteration 22/100000: mean batch inertia: 41.662418, ewa inertia: 42.257358 
Converged (lack of improvement in inertia) at iteration 22/100000
Computing label assignment and total inertia
Clustered sparse matrix in: 14.243s
Filename: experiments/dense_sparse_bench.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    27     38.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    28                             def bench_sparse():
    29                                 # convert the dense matrix in sparse format
    30     38.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(np.random.random((
    31                                     100000,  # 100K 'fake' documents
    32    271.0 MiB    232.5 MiB           500  # 500 dimensions
    33                                 )))
    34    271.1 MiB      0.1 MiB       s = time.time()
    35    271.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       km = MiniBatchKMeans(
    36    271.2 MiB      0.1 MiB           n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', batch_size=100, n_init=10, verbose=1)
    37    598.5 MiB    327.3 MiB       km.fit_predict(sparse_matrix)
    38    598.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       print "Clustered sparse matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would first re-run this benchmark using the *same* random matrix. If not by passing the same matrix, then by setting the seed at the top of each function.

Comment: Good point - done. I was pretty sure the results would be the same though, the difference in the results I got is so strong that it cannot be explained only by the randomness of the generation of the matrix (remember that there is 500*100K, i.e. 50M random numbers generated for each step...)
BTW, I don't want to use the _exact_ same matrix because I wanted to free the memory used by the matrix between the two steps.

Comment: So, if I use regular (not-MiniBatch) KMeans, the convergence iterations and performance are the same, with 812 seconds for dense and 3654 seconds for sparse, which makes sense for your matrices (your sparse matrix is not sparse and the overhead of the sparse encoding substantially increases run time).

Comment: This is right, I would have expected a non-sparse matrix in sparse representation to take more time, but still the same number of iterations. Thank you for your answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

You...have uncovered a bug.

Could you comment on this with your platform, sklearn version, etc. so I can report this to the sklearn developers? It is a bug with [assign_rows_csr](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs_fast.pyx#L261)

I've tightened up your script (assigning the random_state in the MiniBatchKMeans constructor to ensure "the same" results), then started digging. Your results diverge after the first cluster reassignment. Therefore, I modified the k_means_.py function to spit out some variables. At [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L977), I added these print statements inside the "if n_reassign" loop:

```
        print "to_reassign",to_reassign
        print "np.where(to_reassign)",np.where(to_reassign)
        print "new_centers", new_centers
        print "centers", centers[:,0]
        assert False
```

Then I changed verbose to 0, and got this output:

```
>>>>> Dense Matrix Clustering
b
to_reassign [False False False False False False False False False False  True False
 False  True False False  True False  True False]
np.where(to_reassign) (array([10, 13, 16, 18], dtype=int64),)
new_centers [11 24 33 72]
centers [ 0.51612664  0.48724141  0.50478939  0.46328761  0.41928756  0.50768023
  0.48635517  0.48744328  0.59401064  0.55509388  0.33723042  0.37875769
  0.5366691   0.71604087  0.36911868  0.4626776   0.37506238  0.60670616
  0.21136754  0.54321791]

>>>>>> Sparse Matrix Clustering
a
to_reassign [False False False False False False False False False False  True False
 False  True False False  True False  True False]
np.where(to_reassign) (array([10, 13, 16, 18], dtype=int64),)
new_centers [11 24 33 72]
centers [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.33723042  0.          0.
  0.71604087  0.          0.          0.37506238  0.          0.21136754
  0.        ]
```

My modified version of your script:

```
import time
import gc
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans as MiniBatchKMeans
#from memory_profiler import profile


#@profile
def bench_dense(a_random_matrix):
    print ">>>>> Dense Matrix Clustering"
    # create a random dense matrix
    dense_matrix = a_random_matrix.copy()
    s = time.time()
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(
        n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', 
        batch_size=100, 
        n_init=10, verbose=0,
        random_state=37,)
    km.fit_predict(dense_matrix)  # cluster the points
    print "Clustered dense matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)


#@profile
def bench_sparse(a_random_matrix):
    print ">>>>>> Sparse Matrix Clustering"
    # convert the dense matrix in sparse format
    sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(a_random_matrix.copy())
    assert np.all((sparse_matrix == a_random_matrix).sum())
    s = time.time()
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(
        n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', 
        batch_size=100, 
        n_init=10, verbose=0,
        random_state=37,)
    km.fit_predict(sparse_matrix)
    print "Clustered sparse matrix in: %.3fs" % (time.time() - s)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_random_matrix = np.random.random((
        100000,  # 100K 'fake' documents
        500  # 500 dimensions
    ))
    try:
        np.random.seed(42)
        bench_dense(a_random_matrix)
    except AssertionError, e:
        print e
    gc.collect()
    try:
        np.random.seed(42)
        bench_sparse(a_random_matrix)
    except AssertionError, e:
        print e
```

Comment: I'm on Win 7 64-bit, Anaconda 2.1.0 64-bit, Python 2.7, sklearn 0.15.2, numpy 1.9.0

Comment: I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4985)

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5 64-Bits, Python 2.7, scikit-learn 0.15.0, numpy 1.8.0, scipy 0.14.0.
I'll try to investigate the issue a bit more when I have the time to commit to it a bit.